# member variable not an option

Tags: c#

I have many constants I need to move around in one of my classes but I'm not allowed to use member variables. What are some options?

Here's my initial try:

```
private void MyConstants(out int textSize, out int paddingValue, out int borderType, ...)
{
  //Set them here
}

private Method1()
{
  int textSize = 0;
  int paddingValue = 0;
  int borderValue = 0;
  ....

  MyConstants(out textSize, out paddingValue, out borderValue)
}

private Method2()
{
  int textSize = 0;
  int paddingValue = 0;
  int borderValue = 0;
  ....

  MyConstants(out textSize, out paddingValue, out borderValue)
}

//Many more methods...Just seems to repetitive.
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use member variables anywhere or just in this class?  Also is this homework? Why are you not allowed to use member vars?

Comment: just in this one class. No not homework. My hands are tied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Private Class or Struct.

```
private class Variables {
    public int textSize;
    public int paddingValue;
    public int borderValue;
}

private Variables MyConstants{
    get{ return new Variables(){textSize=1, paddingValue=2, borderValue=3};}
}
```

Comment: Could you please illustrate example a tad bit more. Include 2 constants in the example.

Comment: just define those padding, textsize and those in the private class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize in constructor try using **readonly** instead on **const**.
Edit 1:
You can create a class that holds a private Dictionary:like key and value.
put a "object LoadConstant(string)" method in it that will withdraw the data.

```
public static class ConstantManager {
private static Hashtable _consts = new Hashtable();    
private static const keyName = "Name 1";
public static void ConstantManager()
{
    _consts[keyName] = ...;
}
public static Hashtable GetConstants()
{
    var _copy = new Hashtable(_consts);
    return _copy;
}
}

public OtherClass{
public void Method()
{
    var consts = ConstantManager.GetConstants();
    var a = consts[ConstantManager.keyName];
}
}
```